Two-way data binding issue in Blazor: Checkbox not updating bound property
I am a beginner in Blazor
Im not getting any error and why two way data binding not working,
I'm experiencing a two-way data binding issue in my Blazor WebAssembly app. I have a checkbox bound to a boolean property IsActive in my viewmodel. When I toggle the checkbox, the property doesn't update. Here's my code:
I've tried using @bind-value and @bind-value:event="oninput" but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated!"
I'm building a Blazor WebAssembly app and I'm experiencing a two-way data binding issue. I have a checkbox that's bound to a boolean property IsActive in my viewmodel. When I toggle the checkbox, the property doesn't update, and vice versa - when I update the property in code, the checkbox doesn't reflect the change.
Here is my code in
namespace HiddenVilla_Server.Model
{
    public class BlazorRoom
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string RoomName { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
}


<h2 class="bg-light border p-2">
    First Room

</h2>
    Room: @Room.RoomName
<br />
    Price: @Room.Price
<br />

<input type="number" @bind-value="Room.Price" @bind-value:event="oninput" />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" @bind-value="Room.IsActive" checked="@(Room.IsActive?"checked":null)" /> &nbsp; Is Active
<br />
<span>This room is @(Room.IsActive ? "Active" : "Inactive")</span>
<br />


    Room: @Room.RoomName
<br />
    Price: @Room.Price
<br />


@code{
    BlazorRoom Room = new BlazorRoom()
    {
        Id = 1,
        RoomName = "Villa Suite",
        IsActive = true,
        Price = 599
    };
 
}


Error messages:
None, the app runs without errors, but the binding doesn't work as expected.
